# Retrieving old builds for re-deployment in Jenkins

Tags: ant, continuous-integration, jenkins, ivy, artifactory

I have built an automated deployment system using Jenkins, Subversion and ANT on a set of environments. It all works, allowing me to deploy old tagged releases to a set of environments or automatically deploy the latest build using the Subversion Release Manager within Jenkins.

The problem is on the client site, we have to utilise Perforce (which does not currently have a Release Manager plugin within Jenkins [don't really want to write one, but possible]). What is the best way to setup up Jenkins to be able to deploy certain releases to environments? I started looking at Ivy and Artifactory as a possibility.

If anyone has any suggestions, or any guides online, that would be great!

Comment: Any update on your progress / success with Artifactory?

Answer (score 0):

We currently build a WAR file for each Subversion checkin - and make this available with the copy artifact plugin. Redeploy is merely a matter of executing the deploy task for this WAR.